# CouchDB: include_docs in view result with special rev

Tags: couchdb

If I have a view that emits a doc_id as value, then I can get the doc itself by using `&include_docs=true` in the view call.
Is it possible to include a revision number in the value that I am emitting to get a special revision of that doc using `include_docs=true`? 
Greetings, 
Oliver

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because it would not make any sense to do it. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because the document that is provided to the view is the most recent. As a result the only `_rev` available is the most recent one. So the only `_rev` that could ever be output would be that corresponding to the most recent version of the document.

If you modified the document, then the view would be rebuilt, but again, the `_rev` provided to the view would be that corresponding to the most recent version of the document.

Simply put, there is no way to emit a `_rev` that does not correspond to the most recent version of a document.